# What is the better way to split Date string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am getting from api xml data, where one of the xml elements is date time, which nodeValue is always in this format - string: "YYYY-MM-DD". (*I can not request from api, to return me date time in diffrent format*)

My problem is to split and convert this format into this string: "DD.MM.YYYY"

Basicly I did this:

```
var myString = "2015-04-10"; //xml nodeValue from time element
var array = new Array();

//split string and store it into array
array = myString.split('-');

//from array concatenate into new date string format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
var newDate = (array[2] + "." + array[1] + "." + array[0]);

console.log(newDate);
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wyxvbywf/

Now, this code works, but my question is: Is there a way to get same result in fewer steps?

Comment: *"`var array = new Array();`"* The `= new Array()` part of that is immediately made redundant by your next line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

should do the same

```
var newDate = '2015-04-10'.split('-').reverse().join('.')
//                         ^          ^         ^ join to 10.04.2015
//                         |          |reverses (2 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 0 -> 2)
//                         | delivers Array
```

Comment: Funky comment style o.o

Comment: you are the best, tnx for suggestion and explanation, it works great :) upvote + accept (i need to wait for accept 5 min)

Comment: @krnekires glad I coul help ;)

Comment: I need to do the opposite but this one line solution is just mind blowing lol, came as a surprise to me. Thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression that has capture groups and use `String.prototype.replace` to reformat it.

```js
var newDate = myString.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, '$3.$2.$1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
var newDate = '2015-04-10'.split('-').reverse().join('.');
```